# Excel trying to use an equation to call value from different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, equation

I am using an If then statement to call an equation. I need the equation =SUM(E13*$D$5/100)/12 to change the value of the E column starting with 13 and progressively going to E14, E15 etc.

My equation is in column K as it is part of an IF Then.  How do I get E13 to change automaticalling going down my spreadsheet when it's being called.

So when cell B15 calls the above equation it uses the equation =SUM(E14*$D$5/100)/12 and so on going down the page B16 uses E15

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bblb.jpg

Comment: So your formula `=SUM(E13*$D$5/100)/12` is in column K13?  When you drag it down to K14 it will update to `=SUM(E14*$D$5/100)/12` (search for relative and absolute referencing in Excel).  How do you want it to change column E?  You could put in cell E14  `=K14` and it will update to show the contents of cell K14.  Not really sure what you're asking though.

Comment: Did you try simply filling or dragging the formula down?

Comment: My formula is in K3  It is being called from an if then statement in the B column.  So if it is in B14 that is calling it, I want it to use the figure from E13.  If B15 is calling it I want to use E14 in the formula.   

What I am working on is an amortization schedule with a adjusting interest rate.  The figure in E is the principle balance, and it is calculating the amount being paid to interest.

Comment: Could you post a picture of your sheet on imugr and post a link in your original post?

Comment: I take it you have no way to do a screen capture.  while there are ways to do exactly what you want, you will get better results with smaller formula if you simply put the formula inside the if function. `=IF($A15>=$D$9,SUM(E14*$D$5/100)/12,$J$5)`.  If J5 is a formula then put that formula in the place.  Then you can drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to point on the little square at the bottom-right at your first K cell, when the pointer changes in a cross you just simply drag your pointer down till you rich your final cell. Since E13 reference is not an absolute one, you should be able to see E references increment by one. If in your case E13 remains unchanged after this operation you should be able to see a little icon called Paste Formatting on wich you have to click and choose PASTE ALL.